# Selenium: Extract Alt Attribute via XPath

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

I am automating extracting product variations on Amazon and I have the following HTML markup:

```
<ul
    class="a-nostyle a-button-list a-horizontal a-spacing-top-micro swatches swatchesSquare imageSwatches">
    <!-- Please note that in className never append a class with prefix as 'swatch'. It would break something in the twister JS -->
    <li id="color_name_0" class="swatchSelect" data-dp-url="" title="Click to select White">
        <span class="a-list-item">
            <div class="tooltip">
                <span class="a-declarative" data-swatchthumb-action="{"dimIndex":1,"dimValueIndex":0}" data-action="swatchthumb-action">
                    <span id="a-autoid-11" class="a-button a-button-thumbnail a-button-toggle">
                        <span class="a-button-inner">
                            <button id="a-autoid-11-announce" class="a-button-text" type="button">
                                <span class="xoverlay" />
                                <div class="">
                                    <div class="">
                                        <img style="height:36px; width:36px" alt="White"
                                            src="http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41IrdkWxWOL._SS36_.jpg"/>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="" style=" " />
                                </div>
                            </button>
                        </span>
                    </span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I'm using the following XPath to extract the XPath of all colors.

```
.//*[@id='variation_color_name']/ul/li/span/div/span/span/span/button
```

Now I want to extract the alt attribute of each item but when I try using `getAttribute("alt")` it does not return anything. In this case the alt text would be `"White"`. The product I am viewing is: [http://www.amazon.com/dp/B00J46VVKE](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00J46VVKE) . I'm using Java.

Comment: In the html You've posted there is no element with id 'variation_color_name' and the button has no alt attribute. Img has it, so you'd need to add //img at the end of Your XPath.

Comment: But I would need to correlate the button value (which is: a-autoid-11-announce) with the alt value of img (which is: White) - I'm trying to get the XPath / color of each variations..

Comment: Then You need to find button first, and then img inside of it. This should work: buttonFoundWithYourXPath.findElement(By.xpath("//img")).getAttribute("alt");

Comment: Your HTML is not XML, not even proper HTML, see the (now indented) line with `a-declarative`. As written, you cannot use this as input for XPath and if you use a tidying tool, you must make sure to check how the HTML is rewritten, as the structure may be broken/different.

Answer (score 1):

When you have an id attribute there is no need to go to xpath's i believe, unless you have many button's with same id. However here's how you can get the attribute of the img element -

```
WebElement btn = driver.findElement(By.id("a-autoid-11-announce"));
String imgColor = btn.findElement(By.tagName("img")).getAttribute("alt");
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
public class Stackoverflow extends Init {

    @Test
    public void testToGetAltAttribute() throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("Get Attribute....");

        // this element has alt attribute hence that will be displayed.
        assertAndVerifyElement(By.cssSelector("#landingImage"));
        System.out.println("\n#landingImage\n=====================");
        System.out.println(getAttributeOfGivenElement(By.cssSelector("#landingImage"), "alt"));

        // this element do not has alt attribute hence that will not be
        // displayed.
        // it will display msg "element do not have altattribute"
        assertAndVerifyElement(By.id("productTitle"));
        System.out.println("\n#productTitle\n=====================");
        System.out.println(getAttributeOfGivenElement(By.id("productTitle"), "alt"));

    }

    public String getAttributeOfGivenElement(By element, String attributeName) {

        WebElement webElement = getWebDriver().findElement(element);

        if (webElement.getAttribute(attributeName) != null) {
            return webElement.getAttribute("alt");

        } else {
            return "element do not have " + attributeName + "attribute";
        }
    }

    public void assertAndVerifyElement(By element) throws InterruptedException {
        boolean isPresent = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            try {
                if (getWebDriver().findElement(element) != null) {
                    isPresent = true;
                    break;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // System.out.println(e.getLocalizedMessage());
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
        }
        Assert.assertTrue(isPresent, "\"" + element + "\" is not present.");
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want all the colors, you will want to grab the `IMG` elements that contain the ALT attribute. Your XPath ends at a `BUTTON`. Try the code below.

```
List<WebElement> colors = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("ul.imageSwatches img"));
for (WebElement color : colors)
{
    System.out.println(color.getAttribute("alt"));
}
```

The CSS selector is read find a `UL` tag that has the class `imageSwatches` then find all descendant `IMG` tags. You loop through that collection of `IMG` tags and output the `ALT` text.